# Regular Expression to Extract URLs without Unwanted Word

Tags: python, regex

Currently I have strings like this:

```
urls = [
    '<a href=https://energyplus.net/weather-download/asia_wmo_region_2/IND//IND_Kota.424520_ISHRAE/IND_Kota.424520_ISHRAE.epw>Download Weather File</a>',
    '<a href=https://energyplus.net/weather-download/europe_wmo_region_6/ESP//ESP_Alicante.083600_SWEC/ESP_Alicante.083600_SWEC.epw>Download Weather File</a>'
]
```

And a regular expression search like this:

```
for url in urls:
    match = re.search(r'href=[\'"]?([^\'" >]+)', url)
    if match:
        url = match.group(1)
```

`url` returns:

```
https://energyplus.net/weather-download/asia_wmo_region_2/IND//IND_Kota.424520_ISHRAE/IND_Kota.424520_ISHRAE.epw
https://energyplus.net/weather-download/europe_wmo_region_6/ESP//ESP_Alicante.083600_SWEC/ESP_Alicante.083600_SWEC.epw
```

I am hoping to filter out urls that contain the word `SWEC`, so that the second url string is not a match. I think it might have something to do with `(?!SWEC)` but even if that's correct, I am not sure how to incorporate that into the current regex search.

Much appreciated if I can be advised.

Comment: Maybe just `if match and "SWEC" not in url:`?

Comment: Yes. You're exactly right. This is what I am doing, but I am hoping to do it in one line using Regex as it seems neat and I am just hoping to learn how to do it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution using ["The Greatest Regex Trick Ever"](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html)

```
for url in urls:
    match = re.search(r'href=[\'"]?(?:[^\'" >]*SWEC[^\'" >]*|([^\'" >]+))', url)
    if match and len(match.group(1)) > 0:
        url = match.group(1)
```

The trick is to match what you don't want first, then capture what you do want. This will still match urls with SWEC, but the capture group will be empty, so you'll need to adjust your code to handle that.

Answer (score 0):

Regex probably is not required here.  Example...

**Try:**

```
# list of urls
urls = [
    '<a href=https://energyplus.net/weather-download/asia_wmo_region_2/IND//IND_Kota.424520_ISHRAE/IND_Kota.424520_ISHRAE.epw>Download Weather File</a>',
    '<a href=https://energyplus.net/weather-download/europe_wmo_region_6/ESP//ESP_Alicante.083600_SWEC/ESP_Alicante.083600_SWEC.epw>Download Weather File</a>'
]

# check length of list (2)
print(len(urls))

# loop through the list
for i, url in enumerate(urls):
#for url in urls: #if you remove the printing you can revert to this and delete the above enumerate line
    #check if the substring 'SWEC' is in the current element of the list
    if 'SWEC' in url:
        #if so delete that element
        urls.remove(url)
        #print a message to say it's been deleted
        print('Found.  Removing item ' + str(i))

# recheck the length of the list (1)
print(len(urls))
```

**Or even:**

```
urls = [x for x in urls if 'SWEC' not in x]
```

Comment: I am using Regex to extract the url from the <a> tag, so I hope that I can at the same time filter the word in the Regex search.

Comment: I thought 'filter out' meant 'remove from the list of urls I have'?  For regex, maybe: https://regex101.com/r/qu4fFo/1 - but I don't know what you're needing for that.

Comment: Closer to your original regex is [this example](https://regex101.com/r/y41NaM/1) but if you're trying to 'filter out' why do you want to put it in with `url = match.group(1)`.  Maybe I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

You could add `.*` to your negative lookahead `(?!.*SWEC)`, this way the regex will assert that the character sequence does not match any character (except newline) that its follow by the word `SWEC`. This negative lookahead doesn't need to go inside your regex capturing group but it helps reduce the number of steps to find a valid match.

```py
import re

urls = [
    '<a href=https://energyplus.net/weather-download/asia_wmo_region_2/IND//IND_Kota.424520_ISHRAE/IND_Kota.424520_ISHRAE.epw>Download Weather File</a>',
    '<a href=https://energyplus.net/weather-download/europe_wmo_region_6/ESP//ESP_Alicante.083600_SWEC/ESP_Alicante.083600_SWEC.epw>Download Weather File</a>'
]

for url in urls:
    match = re.search(r'href=[\'"]?((?!.*SWEC)[^\'" >]+)', url)
    if match:
        url = match.group(1)
        print(url)

# https://energyplus.net/weather-download/asia_wmo_region_2/IND//IND_Kota.424520_ISHRAE/IND_Kota.424520_ISHRAE.epw
```

Regex101 [example](https://regex101.com/r/3Q4Wya/1)